# Writing a function that takes four arguments which are listed below. Python

Tags: python

I need to write a function that that takes four arguments: day, month, and year as numbers. Weeks must be one of the following: MTWRFSU and converts this date into a human-readable string. 
The output should look like:

Enter day: 28
Enter month: 9
Enter Year: 2014
Enter weekday: U
Date is: Sunday, September 28,2014.

So far my code looks like this and I am pretty stumped can anyone help an average programmer out?:

```
#FUNCTION THAT TAKES 4 ARGUMENTS.
day = int(input('Enter day: '))
month = int(input('Enter month: '))
year = int(input('Enter year:'))
weekday = str(input('Enter weekday: ')) #MTWRFSU

    def total():
        day = int(input('Enter day: '))


        if day >= 32:
            month = int(input('Enter month: '))
        else:
            print('Please enter a valid day for a month. Numbers 1 through 31.')


        if month >= 12:
            year = int(input('Enter Year: '))
        else:
            print('Please enter a valid month: ')











    total()
```

Comment: You need to ask a specific question. This also looks like homework, so you'll get downvoted for that.

Comment: what is/are `MTWRFSU`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Monday, Tuesday, etc.

Comment: I know you made some effort in starting your code, but SO is not a homework service.

Comment: Split the problem up into pieces - you need to convert your weekday (MTWRFSU) argument into a weekday name (Monday, Tuesday). you need to convert your month number (1 to 12), into a month name (January, February etc), and so on. Your function will be in parts like this, with a code segment to deal with each argument - try to write something and come back when you have specific problems. I would suggest you can use 'dictionaries' and 'lists' to help with your conversions (rather than a lot of 'if' statements).

Answer (score -1):

```
import datetime

def total(day, month, year):
   date = datetime.date(year, month, day)
   return '{0:%A}, {0:%B} {0:%d}, {0:%Y}'.format(date)

day = int(raw_input("Please enter the day (1-31)"))
month = int(raw_input("Please enter the month (1-12)"))
year = int(raw_input("Please enter the year"))
print total(day, month, year)
```

This uses python's [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module to handle dates.  The return line uses string formatting, where `{0:?}` refers to the first (only) thing inside of `.format()` and then formats it appropriately (for month, day and year)

Also, don't use input in python 2.x (if this is python 3.x then go ahead)

You might notice that I only use 3 inputs - that's because datetime can figure out the day of the week without being told.  This can be trivially changed to ask for that as well, however.

Comment: Doesn't answer the OPs question - clearly they are being aksed a specific question by a tutor who is teaching about dealing with multiple arguments and formatting outputs.

Comment: I agree that the question is essentialy pointless, given the very rich standard library, but it is actually a good learning exercise in dealing with things like lists and dictionaries to help with converting coded data into readable information, and dealing with multiple arguments.